# How to sort an array given a range?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, range

First of all I am using java and my first objective is to use bubble sort to sort an array in descending order given the range lowindex..highindex (inclusive). So my question is how to sort an array given a range? An example would be greatly appreciated to get me started on doing this.

Comment: Please, StackOverflow is not a coding service. Show was the code you have so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

That wheel has already been invented:

```
Arrays.sort(array, lowIndex, highIndex + 1);
```

See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)).